# Nginx map directive

Tags: nginx

I am trying to exclude requests for *.ong from the nginx log. The following map works:

```
map_hash_bucket_size 128;
map $request $loggable {
    "GET /heizungskeller/graphs/ips_var_48757-day.png HTTP/1.1" 0;
    default 1;
    }
```

however a wildcard does not:

```
map_hash_bucket_size 128;
map $request $loggable {
    "*.png HTTP/1.1" 0;
    default 1;
    }
```

why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wildcard * allows for an easier matching of a prefix or suffix value of a hostname. It only works when the keyword "hostnames" is present at the top of the map block.

Since you are trying to match a request line and not a hostname, you need to use a regular expression instead of a wildcard:

```
map $request_uri $loggable {
    default 1;
    ~*(.*?)\.png$ 0;
}
```

Also, using map directive is not the best way to control what goes into access log and what doesn't. Usually, it's more preferable to introduce a new location that matches your pattern and disable logging there. For example:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|gif|png)$ {
    access_log off;
}
```